# JQuery move list item to end of unordered list

Tags: jquery, html

I am using an unordered list and I want to move the list item with the class of .price to the bottom of the list.

```
<ul class="itemExtraFieldslist">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li class="price">Item 5</li>
    <li>Item 6</li>
    <li>Item 7</li>
    <li>Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried using:

```
$('ul.itemExtraFieldslist').sortable({
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).find('li.price').appendTo(this);
    }
});
```

But this doesn't work. It seems like quite a simple thing but I can seem to get my head around it. I have created a [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/7ruH4/).

There is already an answer on Stack Overflow but it does not work (my version is based on that answer).

Thanks for your help

Comment: correct the following error first "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sortable'"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I don't have an Idea what are you trying to achieve with `sortable`  .
But here is updated  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ruH4/3/)

```
$('ul.itemExtraFieldslist').find('li.price').appendTo('ul.itemExtraFieldslist');
```

Simple. !.

Answer (score 1):

You may be use straight forward code like this

```
var parent = $(".itemExtraFieldslist");    
var childToMoveLast = $(".price", parent).remove();
parent.append(childToMoveLast);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want *Item 5* always at the bottom? Your fiddle works, you forgot to include jQuery UI in the fiddle.

```
jQuery('ul.itemExtraFieldslist').sortable({
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).append($('li.price'));
    }
});
```

**[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ruH4/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

`Sortable` is a function provided by [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/), which your JSFiddle doesn't include. Check the box with jQueryUI and it works: [**Updated JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ruH4/5/)

Also if you want it to work on your own website, you should download the jQuery UI library.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use:

```
$('li.price').insertAfter($('li').last());
```